# Can not compare systemVersion in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

```
#define kIOS8_OR_LATER \
([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0"] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Why the comparison between iOS 8.0 and 10 not work?

```
if (kIOS8_OR_LATER) {
    NSLog(@"1");
} else {
    NSLog(@"0");
}
```

Device:

- Simulator iOS 10 (14A345)
- Real device iPhone 6s iOS 10.0.1 (14A403)

Xcode:

- Version 8.0 (8A218a)

The console keeps logging 0, but works fine in iOS 9.

Comment: `@"10"` comes before `@"8"` alphabetically. You need to use an alpha numeric compare method.

Comment: Also check out this link https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips/#ios-version-checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal string comparison looks at one character at a time. A `1` is ordered before an `8`. So you need to make the comparison numeric:

```
#define kIOS8_OR_LATER \
    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Then the comparison is between `8` and `10`.